# meaning of ON THE WOOD

Tags: word-usage

In the following [passage about Napoleon](https://books.google.com/books?id=IFNBAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=%22if%20he%20thought%20that%20what%20he%20had%20to%20write%20would%20need%20more%20pencils%20than%20he%20had%20he%20would%20keep%20someone%20with%20him%20to%20sharpen%20them%20as%20they%20were%20used%20up%22&source=bl&ots=w0vYzvtbW_&sig=ACfU3U3e75ZxeCqt_nL4_mbSGeiWpi6G5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2j6rG-PHoAhULR6wKHbV8CdQQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22if%20he%20thought%20that%20what%20he%20had%20to%20write%20would%20need%20more%20pencils%20than%20he%20had%20he%20would%20keep%20someone%20with%20him%20to%20sharpen%20them%20as%20they%20were%20used%20up%22&f=false), I can't make out what the writer means by **on the wood** - is it the wooden nub of the pencil after the lead has worn down, or the wooden surface of his desk?

> He ended by giving up pens and ink and substituting pencils. He had a
>   number of them ready on his writing table, which enabled him to write
>   more rapidly and saved the time which it took him to dip his pen in
>   the ink. If he thought that what he had to write would need more
>   pencils than he had he would keep someone with him to sharpen them as
>   they were used up, and with that it often happened that he wrote **on
>   the wood**.

Comment: I guess, worn down to the wooden surround and in need of sharpening (perhaps because his thoughts needed to be written down before they were lost, so he could not spare the time to dip a pen into ink or sharpen a pencil without breaking his thought train).

Comment: @WeatherVane: You mean the wood surrounding the lead?

Comment: The pencil would look like this: https://i0.wp.com/www.tanglevermont.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/blunt-pencil.jpg, i.e. the lead of the pencil would be almost level with, or reduced to, the surrounding wood.

Comment: @Greybeard The link didn't work

Comment: Try https://www.sadellewiltshire.com/2019/05/29/ode-to-mechanical-pencils-redux/ It is the picture of the yellow pencil.

Comment: That's what I thought to - he wrote the pencil down to a nub. Thank you!

Comment: A pencil "nub" though, isn't so much one that has been worn to the wood, but has been sharpened so many times, there is barely any left to hold, like a "stub." For [example](https://images.icanvas.com/3d/pano-horizontal-1/1000-750-f4f5f6/PIM7735.jpg?t=1561043085).

Comment: Quite right!!!!

Comment: And [this one](https://c8.alamy.com/comp/S33X7W/worn-pencil-resting-on-lined-notepaper-S33X7W.jpg) is "worn to the wood."

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind)))